# Sumar variables de PHP cuyo valor sean letras

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Tengo un proyecto en Wordpres en el cual estoy realizando una consulta por base de datos, cuya respuestas pueden ser las letras : D, I o E

Gracias por sus comentarios.
He editado mi nota para explicar un poco mejor mi proyecto y lo que necesito hacer.

Tenemos una plataforma de evaluación psicológica, en donde los usuario deberán responder 3 cuestionarios, uno de ellos mide el porcentaje de dominancia del cerebro (Derecho (D), Izquierdo(I), Dual(E)), para recolectar las respuestas de los usuarios cree una tabla en donde la cruzo con otras. La consulta me trae la respuesta del usuario, asi:

```
//Realizo la consulta para obtener la respuesta
  $select_respuestas="SELECT 
  dom.de_dominancia 
    FROM wp_v_respuestas_estudiantes re
        INNER JOIN wp_v_informe_conf conf ON conf.pk_question =re.re_question_id AND conf.ev_pk = re.re_tipo_evaluacion 
        INNER JOIN wp_v_tipo_evaluacion te ON te.ev_pk = re_tipo_evaluacion AND te.ev_pk = conf.ev_pk  
        INNER JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = re.re_question_id 
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta ON meta.post_id = conf.pk_question AND meta.post_id =re.re_question_id 
        INNER JOIN wp_v_rubrica ru ON ru.ev_pk = te.ev_pk
        inner join wp_v_dominancia dom on re.re_question_id = dom.de_id_answer_lms 
    WHERE conf.ru_pk =154
    AND re.re_user_id =62 
    AND meta.meta_key = 'answers'
GROUP BY conf.pk_question;";

$result_respuestas=$wpdb->get_results($select_respuestas);

//Por medio del Foreach extraigo la respuesta y realizo una consulta a la tabla wp_v_dominancia, tabla que me trae si la dominancia del usuario es D,I o E

 foreach($result_respuestas as $resp){
   $id_resp=$resp->re_pk;
   $num_pregunta=$resp->post_title;
   $respuesta=$resp->re_answer;

 $select_dominancia="SELECT de_dominancia FROM wp_v_dominancia WHERE de_respuesta like ( "."'". $respuesta . "%');";


//Obtengo el valor de la dominancia (D,I o E)                
$result_select_dominancia=$wpdb->get_var($select_dominancia);  
    
//establezco variables en 0 para poder sumar las que se recogen con el foreach
                 
$contD=0;
$contE=0;
$contI=0;   

//En el switch o con un if, quisiera poder recoger esos resultados por letra(dominancia) y poderlos sumar
switch($result_select_dominancia){
   case 'D':
       echo 'El total de "D" es: '.$contD++.'..  ';
   case 'I':
       $contI++;
       echo 'El total de "I" es: '.$contE.'..  ';
   case 'E': 
       $contE++;
       echo 'El total de "E" es: '.$contI.'..  ';
      break;
        }   
}
```

Entonces requiero poder crear unas variables que me sumen los resultados para poderlos contabilizar y poder realizar otro cálculos a partir de ellos

Comment: Pon mas ejemplos de `de_dominancia` con sus correspondientes resultados esperados. Suena que buscas `SELECT de_dominancia, count(1) FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY de_dominancia`

Comment: Yo probé **SELECT COUNT(1) AS Counter FROM bancos WHERE nombre LIKE '%murray%'** en una DB que tengo por hi y me arrojo el dato de todos los bancos que tenían esa palabra. **SELECT COUNT(1) AS D FROM tabla WHERE campo = 'D'** supongo que traería algo similar.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios, he editado mi pregunta para dejar un poco más de claridad frente a mi requerimiento, espero me puedan ayudar, pues las consultas en este caso no creo que me sirvan ya que es son un par de querys anidados por medio de un foreach, sin embargo voy a intentar sumarlos de esta forma. De antemano muchas gracias por la atención y colaboración.

Comment: Quieres sumar ¿qué? resultados; ¿resultados de qué? de los cuestionarios; ¿de cuáles cuestionarios?... etc. explica, hasta el momento se entiende que quieres sumar letras. Insisto, para poder ayudarte debes darnos -por lo menos- un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Comment: Hola, he generado esta grabación creo que me queda más fácil poder explicar lo que requiero http://somup.com/c0Vb33xIkl, adicionalmente he editado el query en la parte superior por si lo llegan a necesitar. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Hola amigos, si me pudieran ayudar les agradezco, aún no he podido dar con la solución. De antemano quedo muy agradecido.